# Is every path a reparametrization of a path with non zero velocity?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, parametrization

Let $\alpha:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a **non-constant** smooth path, and suppose $\alpha'(0)=0$. Do there exist a smooth path $\beta:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and a smooth increasing function $h:[0,1] \to [a,b]$,

such that $\alpha=\beta \circ h,h(0)=0$ and $\beta'(0) \neq 0$. Note $h$ must satisfy $h'(0)=0$.

*Example:* $n=1,\alpha(t)=t^2$, take $h(t)=\alpha(t)$, $\beta=\text{Id}$.

It's easy to shows that if the answer is positive for $n=1$, then it is positive for every dimension $n$. So we are reduced to the one-dimensional case.

Comment: The first thing I would think of here is simply taking the arc length parameterization, which will exist because the curve is smooth.

Comment: @Carl Mummert  If I recall correctly, arclength parametrization only exist when $\alpha' $ is never zero.

Comment: @Carl Mummert: I am not sure about your argument. For $s$ to have a smooth inverse, we need $s'(t)=|v(t)|$ to be nonzero. So a path with zero velocity at a point cannot have an arclength parameterization  around that point, no? (at least not via this standard construction with  inverting $s$).

Comment: Thanks - this at least answers my initial thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily. For a $C^\infty$ counter-example take $\alpha(0)=(0,0)$ and:
$$ \alpha(t) = \left( e^{-1/t}\cos(1/t), e^{-1/t}\sin(1/t) \right), 
\;\; 0<t\leq 1 $$
It spirals around the origin infinitely many times as $t\rightarrow 0$. Whatever the reparametrization, the MVT implies that the direction $\beta'(t)/|\beta'(t)|$ must rotate infinitely many times as $t\rightarrow 0$ which forces $\beta'(0)=(0,0)$ if smooth.

If $\alpha$ is analytic then the claim is partially true. You must have
$$\alpha(t) = (at^n, bt^m) + {\rm (l.o.t)}$$
with say, $n\leq m$ and $a,b$ non-zero. Setting $s=h(t)=t^n$ and $$\beta(s)=(as, bs^{m/n}) +  {\rm (l.o.t)}$$
you get a $C^1$ path for $\beta$. The smoothness of $\beta$ depends upon ratios of powers (also further away in the series). For example, with $n=2,m=3$ $\beta$ is $C^1$ but not $C^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=1$. We have for all $x\in(0,1)$ that $\alpha'(x)\neq 0$ (because $\alpha$ is a path), and so $\alpha$ is strictly monotonous. Hence choosing $\beta=\text{Id}$ and $h=\alpha$ suffice.
$\ $

Keep $n=1$. If instead we let $\alpha$ be a smooth, nowhere constant function on $(0,1)$ which is not a path, then there exists $x_0\in(0,1)$ such that $\alpha'(x_0)=0$.

Assume that $\alpha$ equals the reparametrization $h$ of $\beta$, where $\beta$ has non-zero velocity.
That is $\alpha(x)=\beta(h(x))$ and $\beta'(x)\neq 0$.
Hence $h'(x_0)=0$ since $0=\alpha'(x_0) = h'(x_0) \beta '(h(x_0))$.
Also $h''(x_0)=0$ because otherwise $x_0$ would be an extramum contradicting the monotonicity of $h$.
Differentiating once more we get:
$$\alpha''(x_0) = h''(x_0) \beta '(h(x_0))+h'(x_0)^2 \beta ''(h(x_0)) \\ \alpha''(x_0) = 0\hspace{6.61cm}$$

So a reparametrization exists only if $\alpha''(x) = 0$ whenever $\alpha'(x)=0$.

If we continue differentiating we see that if in addition $\alpha'''(x)=0$ then $\alpha''''(x)=0$ must hold, etc...  Hence one of the following must hold

1. For all $x$ the first non-zero derivative must be an odd order derivative.
2. For those $x$ where 1 doesn't hold, all derivatives of $\alpha$ must be equal to $0$.

A reparametrization may exist only if this condition is satisfied by $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks. So you found a necessary condition, right? Do you know whether it is sufficient? (Also, I don't understand what you mean by "becuase $\alpha$ is a path" in the first sentence-being a path does not restrict any behaviour- a path can be non-injective, its derivative can be zero, etc. according  to the definition I am using, the only limitation is continuity).

Comment: @AsafShachar Say 1. holds, then if you have two roots $x_0,x_1$ of $\alpha'$ (with no roots between them) then the first odd order derivative must have same sign for both roots, because otherwise $\alpha'$ has a root on $(x_0,x_1)$. Hence (along with non-constant-ness) 1. implies that $\alpha$ is strictly monotonous, so the choice of $h$ and $\beta$ at the very top suffices.

Comment: As to 2. I believe that also here a reparametrization exists if and only if $\alpha$ is strictly monotonous, but 2. doesn't imply strictly monotonicity of $\alpha$ so I don't know how to prove it.